# findOneAndUpdate remove element from array if there otherwise put it in there

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, mongoose

Is it possible to write a findOne and update that removes element from an array if it is there but if it is not there add it.

I have a `useful` and `notUseful` array in "reviews" collection. When the user clicks on the useful button once, I want the userId to be added to the useful array and when he clicks on it again it should be taken off. Also I want to make sure that if he clicks the useful button and he is in the notUseful array we pull him from the notUseful array. that is why you see me do a `pull` below.

The below only adds the userId once when I click the button multiple times but I would like a findOneAndUpdate to add and remove the id on button click.

```
function updateArray(){
    var userID = req.user._id ? req.user._id : req.session.anon._id;
    if(req.body.type = "useful"){
        return Review.findOneAndUpdate({_id : req.body.id}, {$addToSet : {useful : userID}, $pull : {notUseful : userID}}, {new : true})
    }


}
updateArray()
    .then(reviewDoc =>{
        console.log("reviewDoc", reviewDoc)
    })
    .catch(err => {console.log(err)})
```

I was wondering if there was an easy way to do it with `findOneAndUpdate`

Maybe there is some conditional query magic I use to do this in one shot.

I could probably put in the query object to test to see if the useful array has the id but I also want to do something if it doesn't have the Id (and I don't know how to do that. )and I want it done in 1 call to the db preferably with `findOneAndUpdate`

Comment: May be you can pull the id from both arrays and then push to one of the array depending on the type of button clicked

Comment: I don't think you can update both arrays at the same time. got error : `MongoError: Cannot update 'useful' and 'useful' at the same time`

Comment: `if(req.body.type == "useful"){
            return Review.findOneAndUpdate({_id : req.body.id}, {$pull : {useful : userID, notUseful : userID}, $addToSet : {useful : userID}});
        }else{
            return Review.findOneAndUpdate({_id : req.body.id}, {$pull : {useful : userID, notUseful : userID}, $addToSet : {notUseful : userID}})
        }`

Comment: I think the error is from pulling and adding to set at the same time to the same array. Good idea though

Comment: but they both are different array's right useful and notuseful should work i think

Comment: but you suggested pulling and pushing on the same array.You said pull from both then push to one of them. And I want to do that in one findOneAndupdate. so in the end you end up pulling and pushing on the same array according to your suggestion. And I think that mongoose doesn't like that. Do you understand. Your pulling from both but your adding back to one of them and mongoose doesn't like that I think

Comment: yeah got it!! And yes mongo doesn't allow update operators on same property. You can update the array on the client side and send it as request body so that those manipulations happens on client side and we have to just call findOneAndUpdate(query, req.body,{ new: true }, function(err, result){})